# Почему при чтении кэша get_transient перезаписываются данные в базе?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, кэширование, wp-query

На сайте под управлением `wordpress` есть большое количество статей с иерархическими категориями *Страна->Город->Район*.
Занимаясь оптимизацией загрузки, я хочу упаковать самую верхнюю родительскую категорию Страна (порядка 250 разновидностей) в метаполе поста `parent_countries`, задействую для этой операции кэширование в `transients`.

Для этих целей запускаю последовательно *2 хука*: первым `add_action('init', 'save_countries')` для кеширования категорий, затем комментирую первый и запускаю второй `add_action('init', 'save_post_action_update')` для непосредственно записи в метатеги постов.

Перед сохранением в **set_transient** убеждаюсь, что массив собрался верный, в базе данных записался сериализованный массив, вроде бы всё хорошо. Но, при попытке его прочесть **get_transient** во втором хуке - получаю уже пустую строку и базе данных поле полностью затирается.. Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(Результат в базе после первого хука, `set_transient` возвращает 1)

1.Проделывал процедуру не один раз - получаю ровно один и тот же результат.

2.В качестве примера: объект `$posts_array` с аналогичной длиной, как у ассоциативного массива записывается и считывается без проблем, всё четко, т.е. это не из-за кривизны `wp` или `mysql`.

3.Пробую решать сохраняя страны в `transient`, т.к. если пробовать напрямую, то память не выдерживает нагрузки сколько бы её не увеличивал.

```
add_action('init', 'save_countries');
function save_countries()
{
    if ( false === ( $posts_array = get_transient( 'parent_countries' ) ) ) {
        $countries = array();
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'post_type'        => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        $posts_array = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
        foreach($posts_array->posts as $post_array)
        {
            $countries[$post_array->ID] = get_cat_name(get_the_category($post_array->ID)[0]->parent);
        }
        print_r($countries); // array([1] => "USA", [2] => "UK",..);
        set_transient( 'parent_countries', $countries, DAY_IN_SECONDS ); 
        wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_action('init', 'save_post_action_update');
function save_post_action_update()
{
    if ( false === ( $posts_array = get_transient( 'posts_array' ) ) ) {
        global $post;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'post_type'        => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        $posts_array = new WP_Query( $args );
        set_transient( 'posts_array', $posts_array, DAY_IN_SECONDS ); 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    $countries = array();

if ( false !== ( $countries = get_transient( 'parent_countries' ) ) ) {
    var_dump($countries); //string ""
    foreach($posts_array->posts as $post_array)
    {
        if( is_array($countries) && count( $countries ) ){
            echo '<p>Update'.$countries[$post_array->ID].'</p>';
            update_post_meta($post_array->ID, 'yacht_country', $countries[$post_array->ID]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Какой результат возвращает set_transient?

Comment: @KAGG Design в первом хуке `add_action('init', 'save_countries')` set_transient возвращает `1`. В описании задачи приложил скрин с бд

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Код рабочий, ничего в нём не менял.

Рассказываю лайфхак: хук `init` отрабатывает при загрузке страницы и если в предыдущие разы я тестировал на полноценной контентной странице на которые размещены изображения, загружены шрифты, вызваны запросы, то в крайний раз открыл исходный код страницы в *html* и обновил в адресной строке.

В результате страница подзависла, в процессе отобразилась *500 ошибка*, но через некоторое время все же загрузилась и отработал `var_dump($countries);`  во втором хуке `init`, а с ним и соответствующие метаполя пополнились записями.
(**transient** в базе сохранился в прежнем виде)
Получается, что нагрузку не вывозил толи хостинг, толи браузер - не знаю.. Но, самое главное, что всё отработало.

Для себя отметил: когда **get_transient** отрабатывает с ошибкой - поле в бд может очиститься.

Может быть это кому-то пригодится